# Photo Upload not working directly from Server/URL i.e using cronjob on Flickr in PHP

Tags: php, cron, flickr, image-uploading

Authentication with our site is working fine and also when I upload on Flickr from temporary file using `async_upload` in PHP,

It's working fine.

But, When we upload photo with `cronjob` in PHP i.e. when we try to upload photo from server directly or using URL, It doesn't upload any photo using `async_upload()` or `sync_upload()` in PHP.

I need your hand,
Thank You

Answer (score -1):

Did you make sure to change your directory to your home / or the specific directory your files exist? That's one of the common mistakes while running from a cronjob. Either you change to the directory required and execute the cronjob php file like

```
* * * * * cd /home/dir; php upload.php
```

Or execute "chdir('/home/dir')" inside your PHP file.